# Spinnaker bakery error: Subnetwork should be specified for custom subnetmode network, invalid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I have installed Spinnaker version: 1.14.11 (local) from scratch on a GCP VM and did hal config. Spinnaker is able to see the compute instances and network in the project. Spinnaker also works fine creating server group / LB and firewall. but once I setup the pipeline to bake and deploy, it fails with the following error.

```
==> googlecompute: Checking image does not exist...
==> googlecompute: Creating temporary SSH key for instance...
==> googlecompute: Using image: ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20190628
==> googlecompute: Creating instance...
    googlecompute: Loading zone: us-east1-b
    googlecompute: Loading machine type: n1-standard-1
    googlecompute: Requesting instance creation...
==> googlecompute: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0]': '{  "network": "projects/pg-us-p-app-xxxx/global/networks/devops",  "accessConfig": [{    "type": "...'. Subnetwork should be specified for custom subnetmode network, invalid
Build 'googlecompute' errored: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0]': '{  "network": "projects/pg-us-p-app-xxxx/global/networks/devops",  "accessConfig": [{    "type": "...'. Subnetwork should be specified for custom subnetmode network, invalid

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> googlecompute: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0]': '{  "network": "projects/pg-us-p-app-xxxx/global/networks/devops",  "accessConfig": [{    "type": "...'. Subnetwork should be specified for custom subnetmode network, invalid

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

```
gcloud compute networks list  | grep devops
devops                       CUSTOM       REGIONAL
```

HAL config:

```
google:
      enabled: true
      accounts:
      - name: my-gce-account
        requiredGroupMembership: []
        providerVersion: V1
        permissions: {}
        project: pg-us-p-app-xxxx
        jsonPath: /home/spinnaker/.gcp/gce.json
        alphaListed: false
        imageProjects: []
        consul:
          enabled: false
          agentEndpoint: localhost
          agentPort: 8500
          datacenters: []
      primaryAccount: my-gce-account
      bakeryDefaults:
        templateFile: gce.json
        baseImages: []
        zone: us-east1-b
        network: "devops"
        useInternalIp: true
```

`devops` is a custom VPC network, where should I provide the Subnetwork? or how to fix this error?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolved this issue by passing "gce_subnetwork" as an "Extended Attributes" under "Bake Configuration" in the pipeline.

Hope this might help some.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when attempting to create a compute instance using the `gcloud compute` CLI command.

### Solution

My solution was to add the `--subnet` flag and the `--zone` flag with a zone value corresponding to the zone of the subnetwork:

### Example Command

```
gcloud compute instances import kbull-instance2022 \
  --os=debian-9 \
  --network=bull \
  --subnet=pen \
  --zone=us-east1-a \
  --source-uri=gs://bull-pen-image/bull-image-virtualbox.ova \
  --custom-cpu=2 \
  --custom-memory=2048MB
```